# How do I make my variable levels appear in my regression summary table in R?

Tags: r, regression

My model has two IVs: `t` and `story_type`. The levels of `t` are `t1, t2, t3` and for `story_type` are (for simplicity, we'll call them) `A, B, C, D`. Previously everything worked as usual--I would see `story_typeA, story_typeB, story_typeC` in my model summary. For some reason, the summary (as of my last refresh) now shows the following, with numeric markers (`story_type1, story_type2, story_type3`) rather than the actual level labels:

```
Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.2047159  0.0175622 239.419  < 2e-16 ***
t1           0.0001681  0.0464882   0.004    0.997    
t2          -0.2313327  0.0392468  -5.894 3.76e-09 ***
story_type1 -0.0934701  0.0034883 -26.795  < 2e-16 ***
story_type2 -0.1252931  0.0035278 -35.516  < 2e-16 ***
story_type3  0.2304953  0.0031908  72.238  < 2e-16 ***
```

I tried converting `story_type` to a factor (it was originally a character vec), this didn't help. I've also carefully run through all of the preceding code several times now to check whether something had been changed accidentally, also to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening, and how I'd be able to see my level names again?

(e.g. I'd have a summary that looks as follows: )

```
Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.2047159  0.0175622 239.419  < 2e-16 ***
t1           0.0001681  0.0464882   0.004    0.997    
t2          -0.2313327  0.0392468  -5.894 3.76e-09 ***
story_typeA -0.0934701  0.0034883 -26.795  < 2e-16 ***
story_typeB -0.1252931  0.0035278 -35.516  < 2e-16 ***
story_typeC  0.2304953  0.0031908  72.238  < 2e-16 ***
```

EDIT:

So I spun up a toy dataset and am getting the same problem:

```
set.seed(16)
scores <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 1)
type <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5)

df <- data.frame(scores, type)

model <- lm(scores ~ type, data = df)
summary(model)
----------------------------------------------
> Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.1105     0.2335    0.47     0.64
type1        -0.0731     0.4045   -0.18     0.86
type2         0.6081     0.4045    1.50     0.15
type3        -0.1164     0.4045   -0.29     0.78
```

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ scores: num  -0.4684 -1.006 0.0636 1.025 0.5731 ...
 $ type  : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
```

As a factor it returns the same summary, without the level names appearing in the output.

Comment: Maybe your levels changed, do `levels(story_type)` to check that, and `levels(story_type) = c("a","b","c","d")` to correct it

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro that's the strange thing, they're already 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', as expected. I've inspected the data and nothing has changed, everything looks as it should.

Comment: add `str(data)` to the question

Comment: to me it gives the correct output

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk right, so coming back to my original question...what could be making my code behave this way?

Comment: Also gives correct output for me. Perhaps add `sessionInfo()`? Do you see the problem if you restart R?

Comment: @GregorThomas restart fixed it. Embarrassingly simple. Thank you!